# How to show an input filed based on Select option with the same ngModel

Tags: angular

```
<form #uform="ngForm">
Service
              <select name="type" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="create.type">
                  <option value="Youtube">Youtube</option>
                  <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
                  <option value="Custom">Custom</option>
              </select>
 Custom
              <input *ngIf="create.type=='Custom'" name="type" class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="create.type">
<button (click)="createDetails();" class="create" type="submit">Create now</button>
</form>
```

When i select the custom option the text field shows up but when i edit it, it goes away because the value of `create.type` changes. Now it is mandatory to have the same name type otherwise the back end wont accept it.
All i want is if the custom is selected then the user should enter the text in the input field and the create object should be updated to the correct value.

```
create: any ={  }


createDetails() {
this.api.create(create).subscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a different ngModel on input and then inside createDetails function you can use that value to call your backend

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are replacing the 'create.type' property.

You can remove [(ngModel)]="create.type" from your input, then you can access your form data in the ts file and manipulate it as you want, and at the end send it to backend.